# Using aws_secret in ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, credentials, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to retrieve password from aws secret manager using ansible 2.8 using lookup.

Below things are not working for me:

1. In .bashrc, I have exported region
2. Ansible Environment Variables in task
3. Setting up ansible variables in pre_tasks

```yaml
- hosts: StagingApps
  remote_user: staging
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
  - debug:
      var: "{{ lookup('aws_secret', 'staging_mongodb_pass', region='us-east-1') }}"
      msg: "{{ query('aws_secret', 'staging_mongodb_pass', region='us-east-1') }}"
      environment:
        region: 'us-east-1'
```

Error Message:

> FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'aws_secret'. Error was a , original message: 'Requested entry (plugin_type: lookup plugin: aws_secret setting: region ) was not defined in configuration.'"}

Comment: I'm pretty sure the environment name is [`AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.156/guide/configuration.html#environment-variable-configuration) an not just `region`

Comment: I have tried all combinations .bashrc and confured .aws/config with multiple aws profiles (AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-1", AWS_REGION="us-east-1", region="us-east-1"). None of these are working

Comment: No, you are confusing kwargs with an **environment** variable; I specifically said the _environment variable_, if for no other reason than you mentioning `.bashrc` and also having `environment:` in your example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Ansible released this lookup plugin in a broken state. They have an issue and a PR open to fix it:

- https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/54790
- https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/54792

Very disappointing, as I've been waiting for this plugin for many months.

Answer (score 3):

below playbook has worked for me

```
  - name: "register mongodb from secretsmanager"
    shell: "aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id staging_mongodb"
    register: mongodb_pass
    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1

  - set_fact:
      mongodb_pass_dict: "{{ mongodb_pass.stdout | from_json | json_query('SecretString')  }}"

  - set_fact:
      mongodb_pass_list: "{{ ['staging_mongodb'] | map('extract', mongodb_pass_dict) | list  }}"

  - set_fact:
      mongodb_pass: "{{ mongodb_pass_list[0] }}"

    - template:
      src: application.properties.j2
      dest: application.properties
      mode: 0644
      backup: yes
```